# C# CSOM check internet connection

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, networking, csom

I developed a console application using `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` library. Basically what it does is check if a folder exists in a list (creates if not), creates a list item and attaches files to that list. All seems to work fine, but we ran the application on a computer with slower network connection and it's not working all the time, because the `ClientContext` throws an

> "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

exception just after `context.ExecuteQuery();`. This seems to be thrown whenever the client is unable to connect to the sharepoint site. Now the question is:

Is there a way to handle internet connectivity issues with `ClientContext`? I'd like to know if the client failed to connect and maybe retry some operations after some time, not just get a null reference exception which doesn't tell me much about the connectivity.

Comment: You could fire up a `HttpRequest` to the REST endpoint to see if the instance is alive.. `%SITE_COLLECTION_URL%/_api/web` it will return a 401 to authenticate but at least you will know it is there...